# Get Last record form my sqlite db using go

Tags: go

I want to query my sqlite db to get the last id in my book table then insert the data with the last id + 1. I am new to Go and I can't figure out how to set my lastid int variable. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
func getBookLastID() {

  var lastid int
  err := db.QueryRow("select max(id) from books").Scan(&lastid)
  fmt.Println(lastid)
  return (lastid + 1)
}

func insertBook(name, author string, pages int, publicationDate time.Time) (int, error) {
        //Create
        var bookID int

        var lastid int 
        lastid = getBookLastID()

        err := db.QueryRow(`INSERT INTO books(id, name, author, pages, publication_date) VALUES($1, $2, $3, $4, $5)`, lastid, name, author, pages, publicationDate).Scan(&bookID)

        if err != nil {
                return 0, err
        }

        fmt.Printf("Last inserted ID: %v\n", bookID)
        return bookID, err
}
```

Comment: what does your schema look like? I typically use autoincrement for the id column on a table

Comment: I figured it out I will post my results. @Nevermore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing "int" in the func

Wrong:

```
func getBookLastID() {....
```

Correct:

```
func getBookLastID() int {....
```

Correct All:

```
func getBookLastID() int { 

    var id int

    err := db.QueryRow("select ifnull(max(id), 0) as id from books").Scan(&id)
    if err != nil {
      panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("New record ID is:", id + 1)
    return id + 1
}

func insertBook(name, author string, pages int, publicationDate time.Time) (int, error) {
    //Create

    lastid := getBookLastID() 


    res, err := db.Exec(`INSERT INTO books(id, name, author, pages, publication_date) VALUES($1, $2, $3, $4, $5)`, lastid, name, author, pages, publicationDate)

    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }

    rowsCreated, err := res.RowsAffected()

        if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }

    return int(rowsCreated), err

}
```

Comment: why didn't you use AUTOINCREMENT on the ID column?